# How to use a package as a plugin - Angular

Tags: angular, npm

How exactly we install a npm package as a plugin.I can see we exporting a module but where is everything wired up?

For example the package for webpack analyzer which despite all the attempts i couldn't get it to work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

it gives you this code

```
    const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
   new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
 ]
```

}

What steps exactly should i follow?

Should i create a ts file paste the code in and import it in the app.module.ts?

Comment: For this particular library, the approach should probably not be to treat it like an angular module. Instead, make it a cli/npm script like in the example here: https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack

Comment: Hello Katherine thanks for the comment.Unfortunately i have already seen this article and end up with a  ""Schema validation failed with the following errors:
 Data path ".statsJson" should be boolean."" error and didn't find anything similar in the net.